# as keyword for enum in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this type

```
type Abc = 'a' | 'b' | 'c'
```

how can I make `myObj.something` type `Abc`?

I can think of valueOf:

```
const myObj = {
    something: ['a', 'b', 'c'] as valueOf Abc
}
```

but I wonder why it doesn't work

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggRgYygXigcgIZqgH3XbPNBNAKFEigDcMAbAVwgHsAzAHgBUA+FKDgbQDWEEKz4BdUqQRMAdgGdgUALYgA8nABWvAN6koBqPKbKIwABYBLWQHMAXFH6Y0AGnyv0JcVAzzqdRjV2eAQuUgBfIA

Comment: Abc is type not object instance. `something: ['a', 'b', 'c'] as Abc[]` this will work

Comment: @tom10271 it doesn't mate

Comment: If it does not work then why are you accepting the answer down below?

Comment: @tom10271 sorry I got it wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your case you are trying to set `['a', 'b', 'c']` (which is an array) as `Abc`. You should define myObj.something as an array of type `Abc`, with `Abc[]`

```js
const myObj = {
    something: ['a', 'b', 'c'] as Abc[]
}
```

Comment: is it working? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggRgYygXigcgIZqgH3XbPNBNAKFIQHsA7AZ2CgFsQB5OAKxSgG9Sp+otSowjAAFgEtqAcwBcUANqY0AGnyr0JALpQMtWIlIBfIA

Comment: so it works https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggRgYygXigcgIZqgH3XbPNBNAKFIQHsA7AZ2CgFsQB5OAKxSgG9Sp+otSowjAAFgEtqAcwBcUANqY0AGnyr0JALpQMtWIgVbSAXyA

Answer (score 0):

Please make a interface first.
Then use it. Like this

```
type Abc = 'a' | 'b' | 'c'

// make interface
interface myObject {
    something: Abc[]
}

// use the interface
const myObj:myObject = {
    something: ['a']
}
```